# How to pause a task scheduled by DispatchQueue

Tags: swift

I have a game where I am creating a pause button. The pause button needs to stop and then resume a specific task:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
        if self.ongoing {
            self.dispose()
        }
})
```

I was thinking of doing this by keeping track of when this task was scheduled and keeping track of when the pause started so I could then schedule a new task with an updated time after the player unpauses. However, I don't know how to cancel the old task. Is there an easier way of freezing/stopping temporarily a task scheduled by DispatchQueue?

Comment: Hope this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492707/how-to-stop-cancel-suspend-resume-tasks-on-gcd-queue

Comment: You don’t `suspend` tasks. You `suspend` private queues which prevents anything from starting on that queue (but does nothing with tasks already running on that queue). I am hard-pressed to imagine using GCD queues for your use-case. Sure, if you’re already using queues to manage the state of your app (e.g. dispatch timers), fine, but personally I’d be inclined to pursue non-GCD solutions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task has already been launched, the easiest way to do this is to have an `isCancelled` variable that your task's code repeatedly checks inside its main loop. To cancel the task, you simply set the `isCancelled` variable to `true`. You may want to use a lock and/or semaphore to make the variable thread-safe. If you use `OperationQueue` instead of `DispatchQueue`, the `Operation` object contains an `isCancelled` operation which is ready-made for this purpose (and if you manage to set the `isCancelled` property before the operation has even started, `OperationQueue` will skip running it at all).

Comment: FYI, `DispatchWorkItem` already has an [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780829-iscancelled) property. You can then [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel) the `DispatchWorkItem` and that existing `isCancelled` property will be set for you.

Comment: @Rob That is quite nice; I wasn't aware of that.